# How to navigate to another component in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I've got a function, which upload image and I would like to after end this function navigate to next component. In app-routing.module.ts I made a necessary configuration, but I don't know, how to do navigation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using angular.

```js
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

// ...

  constructor(private routerEx: RouterExtensions) {
  }

  yourFunction(): void {
    // do your stuff

    this.routerEx.navigate(['your route']);
  }
```

Comment: Even if I do this from modal dialog  ?

Comment: You'd call this function in the callback from your modal. It's hard to answer more specifically without any source to work from. Can you provide a [playground](https://play.nativescript.org)?

Comment: This is my playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vkpsJ2&v=9

Comment: When you handle the modal response (`if (response == ...`) do the `this.routerEx.navigate` that I provided above in my answer.

Comment: Ok, it works, I add `onClose(status:string){
        this.params.closeCallback(status);
    }` and in function uploadPhoto `this.onClose('success')`